# Forms , widgets

Tags: python, django, forms, виджет

Есть такая форма:

```
class SpisokForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = shops_spisok
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'obj_1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Товар', 'max_length': '35'}),
            'number_1': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Кол-во', 'max': '999999', 'min': '0'}),
            'price_1': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Примерная цена', 'max': '999999', 'min': '0'}),
```

Модель:

```
obj_1 = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=35, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Максимальная кол-во символов не должно превышать 35", verbose_name="Товар1")
number_1 = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="Кол-во товара", verbose_name="Кол-во")
 price_1 = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="Примерная цена", verbose_name="Цена")
```

Форма в шаблоне:

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>№</th>
            <th>Наименование товара</th>
            <th>Количество товара</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>                                                                                                            <!-- 1-10 -->
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>{{ form.obj_1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.number_1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.price_1 }}</td>
        </tr>
```

Проблема в том, что
1) В виджете формы placeholder работает для `TextInput`, а для `NumberInput` нет. Как прикрутить и к нему?
2) Как правильно в виджете сделать проверку/поставить условие для `TextInput` на длину текста? В моделе есть ограничение, но хочу чтобы проверяло на уровне ФронтЕнда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В исходном **коде появляется** или нет в вопросе не указано.
Возможны несколько вариантов, начиная с того что просто ваш браузер не отображает placeholder для элементов типа number

1) Для старых браузеров существует такой способ

```
<input placeholder="Amount" onfocus="this.type='number';">
```

Действует до первого нажатия, отображает как текстовое поле, но показывает.

**Если отсутствует в исходном html коде.**

1) Прописать вручную и проверить что все работает.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Кол-во" name="id_number_1">
```

Обратите внимание на name элемента, он не number_1 как мы писали в коде.

2) Когда элементов много удобнее править все из шаблона, для этого используем шаблонные фильтры.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='add_placeholder')
def add_placeholder(field, placeholder):
return field.as_widget(
    attrs={"placeholder": placeholder}
)
```

шаблонная часть,

```
{{ form.number_1|add_placeholder:"Кол-во" }}
```

Относительная проблема шаблонных тегов, это то что можно передать только один параметр, решается разбиванием строки по разделителю info.split("/") дальше части распределяем как нужно. Недостаток, нужно придерживаться порядка следования.

```
{{ form.number_1|add_placeholder:"Кол-во/0/999999" }}
```

Пример для bootstrap

```
@register.filter(name='add_bootstrap')
def add_bootstrap(field, info):
    info = info.split("/")
    css = info[0]
    placeholder = info[1]
    min = info[2]
    max = info[3]
    return field.as_widget(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": placeholder,
            "class": css,
            "min": min,
            "max": max,
        }
    )
```

в шаблоне

```
{{ form.number_1|add_bootstrap:"form-control col-md-8/Кол-во/0/999999" }}
```

По проверке элемента как хотите так и проверяйте на front end. Любым удобным способом, начиная от ограничения кол-ва символов в поле. Желательно чтобы посетителю тоже было удобно. Django ограничений не накладывает.